# Plot the Centroid of a Dataset in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

In matlab I have painted a figure with X1,Y1,Z1 axis using

```
h=plot3(X1,Y1,Z1,'y*');
```

And `X1`,`Y1` and `Z1` are row matrix with the shape. Now I want to highlight the point `(x,y,z)` consisting of the average of each row matrix in the same figure. How to highlight the average point in sharp or color and avoid being covered by row matrix point. I really want source program about matlab like `plot3()`.

Comment: Let me know if that'll do it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to highlight the centroid of the cluster. You can do it with the following code.

```
x1 = rand(10,1);
y1 = rand(10,1);
z1 = rand(10,1);

plot3( x1, y1, z1, 'y*' );
hold on;
scatter3( mean( x1 ), mean( y1 ), mean( z1 ), 'r' );
hold off;
```

You can use `scatter3` to plot the point in red using the 'r' parameter. Circles are the best for this job and it won't be covered as it is hollow. You can use different [colors](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorspec.html) or [markers](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linespec.html) built into Matlab.

Here are the results

[image]

Unless you're plotting a trajectory, if you are plotting points, I suggest you use `scatter3` instead of `plot3`. It gives the following plot.

[image]

I would also suggest using blue instead of yellow for better visibility.

Comment: That could work too. Either `plot3` or scatter will work to plot your data but you said you used `plot3`... Just use scatter to plot the centroid.

Comment: That's why I said "Unless you're plotting a trajectory, if you are plotting points, I suggest you use scatter3 instead of plot3. It gives the following plot."